# Working with Shopify Order API

Tags: api, shopify

I'm making a private application for my Shopify store. The application is supposed to replace the standard checkout process.
Everything works well, the order is sent to my Shopify store and I can see it in the admin area, the only problem I'm facing is that after the order is placed the cart properties will not reset (the customer's products are still present in the cart and the most important, the cart token does not change).
Anyone has any idea why is this happening and how I can fix it? I was thinking that maybe I'm not sending enough information to the store but I might be wrong. This is what i'm sending:

```
$product = $shopify('POST /admin/orders.json', array(), array
    (
      'order' => array
      (
        "email" => $email,
        "fulfilment_status" => "",
        "send_receipt" => true,
        "line_items" => $products,
        'customer' => array
        (
          "first_name" => $firstName,
          "last_name" => $name,
          "email" => $email
        ),
        'billing_address' => array
        (
          "first_name" => $firstName,
          "last_name" => $name,
          "address1" => $adress,
          "phone" => $telefon,
          "city" => $city,
          "province" => $province,
          "country" => $country,
          "zip" => $zip
        ),
        'note_attributes' => array (
        array("name" => "Company", "value" => $company),
        array("name" => "CUI","value" => $cui),
        array("name" => "Registration","value" => $reg)
        ),
        'shipping_address' => array
        (
          "first_name" => $firstName,
          "last_name" => $name,
          "address1" => $adress,
          "phone" => $phone,
          "city" => $city,
          "province" => $province,
          "province_code" => $provinceCode,
          "name" => $firstName." ".$name,
          "country_code" => $countryCode,
          "country" => $country,
          "zip" => $zip
        ),
        'shipping_lines' => $shipping,
        'financial_status' => 'pending'
      )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you do the `POST`, there'll be a `order_status_url` field in the response data. Take the user to that URL and the cart will be reset.

Please note, that the `order_status_url` will be null unless the order is completed with the checkout processes.

Correction: Orders place through API can't be taken to the checkout process, in this case check below.

You can clear the cart by doing an `AJAX GET` to `/cart/clear.js`
You can clear the attributes/note by doing `AJAX POST` to `/cart/update.js` with `"attributes": {}` or `"note":""` respectively.

Comment: There is no other way?

Comment: No. But it's very easier to implement. You are anyway required to take them to the thank you URL which is same as the `checkout_url`

Comment: I couldn't find any field called "checkout_url" in the response data of /admin/orders.json...i'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: My mistake. It's `order_status_url`. Updated the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer again. Please note, cart token doesn't change unless the cart is cleared through the checkout process.

Comment: So it should look like this with javascript?
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: \"POST\",
        url: '/cart/update.js',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: 'attributes':{},
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
</script>"

Comment: `$.ajax({
    url:"/cart/update.js",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{attributes:{}} ,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success:function(){ ... },
    error:function(){ ... });`

Comment: I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :", do you have any idea why? Also, I slightly modified your script, since my private app is hosted on another domain, I set the dataType to "jsonp".

Comment: Replace `...` with some function or keep blank.. Also it has to run from the store website as the cart is linked to current session on website..

Comment: This is the exact code that i'm using:
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:\"http://xxxxxxx.myshopify.com/cart/update.js\",
        type:\"POST\",
        dataType:\"jsonp\",
        data:{attributes:{}},
        contentType:\"application/json; charset=utf-8\", 
        success:function(){},
        error:function(){}
      });
    };
    </script>";

Comment: Where are you placing the `window.onload` function?

Comment: You mean where the echo is placed? Somewhere in the middle of the document but I don't think that this is important since right after this I have another echo that is very similar, the only difference is that it sends POST to /cart/clear.js and for the success function I use the Shopify.clear() function to clear the cart, and it works.

Comment: I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" for this script. One question: are you sure that this will reset the cart token? because this is what I actually need to reset once the checkout is complete.

Comment: No. Cart token will change only when a checkout process is done. Why don't your give this a try `https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/sell-through-the-checkout-api` ?